# How can I rotate my surface in Pygame without using the rotate command?

Tags: python, python-3.x, rotation, pygame

The code for rotating is:

```
pygame.transform.rotate(surface, angle)
```

But I don't want to use the code.  I want to write a code for rotating the surface myself.  How can I do that?

Comment: Your first step would be to tell us why you don't want to use that command... otherwise, we have no idea what you want, nor why you want it!

Comment: And why would you do that? This question is not very good...

Comment: To rotate the surface yourself your best option is to convert it to a [surfarray](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surfarray.html) and apply a transformation matrix (more specifically a [rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix)). Pygame is not very good at manually manipulating pixels so it most likely will be very slow. Using `pygame.transform.rotate` is your best option, but if the main focus was that you wanted to learn then you might want to look into linear algebra and matrix calculations. The question as it currently is, is too broad.

Comment: @XCode It's not a bad question per se but it's just many ways to answer it and all answers would require very long explanations. I personally think this is a good question if it would just be narrowed down and instructions on how it would function (which restrictions there are, should it return a surface of the same size, etc) were provided. It would also be good to have code examples (attempts to solving the issue) to work from. However, to blatantly question the relevance of what OP want to accomplish followed by calling it bad is neither constructive nor very nice.

Comment: Are you looking for a matrix multiplication? I was hoping pygame had an easy option, but I guess I will just jump into image anti-aliasing...

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ways to tackle the problem, but I've interpreted it as it should rotate the image by degrees, counter-clockwise and resize the image as needed. I also included a `crop` function to get rid off excessive noise. Although, there are still problems with my implementation, mainly that it's [aliased](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing). To fix it you can take look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42196483/6486738) answer.

To rotate an image you first need to convert it to an matrix. This can be done with the help of `pygame.surfarray.array3d`, but it requires you to have numpy installed. Then we need a [rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) and a new matrix which we'll copy all the pixels from our image to. When multiplying a position vector with the rotation matrix you'll get a new position vector. So all we're doing is iterating through the x-y coordinates of the image, applying the rotation matrix to each coordinate and then add the pixel at then new coordinate in our new matrix.

```
import numpy as np
from math import sin, cos, radians
import pygame
pygame.init()

SIZE = WIDTH, HEIGHT = 720, 480
FPS = 30
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SIZE)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()


def crop(array, background=(0, 0, 0)):
    rows, cols, _ = array.shape
    left, right, top, bottom = 0, cols, 0, rows

    for row in range(rows):
        if not np.all(array[row] == background):
            top = row
            break
    for row in range(rows - 1, top, -1):
        if not np.all(array[row] == background):
            bottom = row
            break

    np.transpose(array, axes=(1, 0, 2))

    for col in range(cols):
        if not np.all(array[col] == background):
            left = col
            break
    for col in range(cols - 1, left, -1):
        if not np.all(array[col] == background):
            right = col
            break

    np.transpose(array, axes=(1, 0, 2))

    return array[top:bottom+1, left:right+1]


def rotate(surface, angle):
    rect = surface.get_rect()
    width, height = surface.get_size()
    image_array = pygame.surfarray.array3d(surface)

    angle = radians(angle)

    # Rotation matrix: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix
    rotation = np.array(
        ((cos(angle), -sin(angle)),
         (sin(angle), cos(angle))
         ), dtype=np.float16
    )

    # Rotates the corners of the image because the distance between 2 opposite corners will always be the furthest
    # distance. This helps us calculate the new width and height of our new rotated image.
    y_list, x_list = zip(*(
        (position @ rotation) for position in (rect.topleft, rect.topright, rect.bottomleft, rect.bottomright)
    ))
    min_x, min_y = min(x_list), min(y_list)
    new_width = int(abs(min_x - max(x_list))) + 1
    new_height = int(abs(min_y - max(y_list))) + 1

    # Since we're rotating the image at the topleft corner and not in the center it'll be moved. By adding the offset
    # we just move it back in place.
    offset = -int(min_y), -int(min_x)

    rotated_image_array = np.zeros(shape=(new_height, new_width, 3), dtype=np.uint8)

    for row in range(height):  # Not the newly calculated height, but the original image's height.
        for col in range(width):
            y, x = (row, col) @ rotation + offset
            rotated_image_array[int(y), int(x)] = image_array[row, col]

    rotated_image_array = crop(rotated_image_array)

    return pygame.surfarray.make_surface(rotated_image_array)


def main():
    running = True
    original_image = pygame.Surface((200, 200))
    original_image.fill(pygame.Color('red'))
    image = original_image
    while running:

        clock.tick(FPS)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    running = False
                elif event.key == pygame.K_1:
                    print('Reset image.')
                    image = original_image
                elif event.key == pygame.K_2:
                    print('Starting rotating.')
                    time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
                    image = rotate(image, 20)
                    time = pygame.time.get_ticks() - time
                    print('Finished rotating in {:.4E} s.'.format(time / 1000))

        screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
        screen.blit(image, image.get_rect(center=(WIDTH // 2, HEIGHT // 2)))
        pygame.display.update()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score -2):

```
import pygame

SIZE = 1000, 900

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SIZE)

a=0

done = False

screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

other1 = pygame.image.load("image.jpg")

screen.blit(other1, (0, 0))

while not done:

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:

                a=a+90

                other2 = pygame.transform.rotate(other1, a)

                screen.blit(other2, (0, 0))

            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:

                a=a-90

                other2 = pygame.transform.rotate(other1, a)

                screen.blit(other2, (0, 0))

    screen.fill((0,0,0))

    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: This answer doesn't attempt to answer the question. You've just copied the code from [your question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42153719/how-can-i-rotate-an-image-in-pygame-with-out-current-commandwith-out-pygame-tr), which is a duplicate of this question.