# how can i rotate an image in pygame with out current command(with out *pygame.transform.rotate* command)?

Tags: python, rotation

```
import pygame    
SIZE = 1000, 900    
pygame.init()    
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SIZE)    
a=0    
done = False    
screen.fill((0, 0, 0))    
other1 = pygame.image.load("image.jpg")    
screen.blit(other1, (0, 0))    
while not done:

    for event in pygame.event.get():    
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:    
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:    
                a=a+90    
                other2 = pygame.transform.rotate(other1, a)    
                screen.blit(other2, (0, 0))    
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:    
                a=a-90    
                other2 = pygame.transform.rotate(other1, a)    
                screen.blit(other2, (0, 0))    
    screen.fill((0,0,0))    
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 0):

One liners using [numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.rot90.html):

Clockwise

```
pygame.surfarray.make_surface(numpy.rot90(pygame.surfarray.array2d(other1)))
```

Counter-clockwise

```
pygame.surfarray.make_surface(numpy.rot90(pygame.surfarray.array2d(other1), 3))
```